# Android GCM - Send different payload to each user in registration_ids array

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

In a multicast GCM trigger, I want to send different payload to each user.
My GCM json corresponding array is as follows:

```
$fields = array(
'collapse_key' => 'demo',
'registration_ids' => $registration_ids,
'data' => array('myjson' => 'abc'),
);
```

Consider the registeration_ids array as follows:

```
$registration_ids => array('id1','id2','id3');
```

With the above mentioned GCM json corresponding array, all the users get same value of 'myjson'. Is there any way that i can design the json corresponding array such that 'id1' gets 'abc' as the value of 'myjson', 'id2' gets 'def' as the value of 'myjson'... and so on?

Comment: multicast means sending the same message to multiple users in a single request, you can't multicast for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible. A multicast message allows you only to send the same message to multiple registration IDs.

> - A 3rd-party application server can either send messages to a single device or to multiple devices. A message sent to multiple devices simultaneously is called a multicast message.
> - To send a single message to multiple devices owned by a single user, you can use a notification_key, as described in User Notifications.
> - You have 2 choices in how you construct requests and responses: plain text or JSON.
> - However, to send multicast messages, you must use JSON. Plain text will not work.
>
> **registration_ids**   A string array with the list of devices (registration IDs) receiving the **message**. It must contain at least 1 and at most 1000 registration IDs. To send a multicast **message**, you must use JSON. For sending a single message to a single device, you could use a JSON object with just 1 registration id, or plain text (see below). A request must include a recipient—this can be either a registration ID, an array of registration IDs, or a notification_key.

Note that in a multicast message you are still sending a single message. The only parameter that can have multiple values in the JSON request is the `registration_ids`.

To send different messages to different devices, you must send one request (either JSON with a single registration ID or plain text) for each device.

Answer (score -2):

Make it a map like this:

```
{
  regn: [{
          regn_id: id_1,
          data: abc
         },
         {
          regn_id: id_2,
          data: defg
         },
       ..]
}
```

Call it in a `JSONArray` object.